# KalaSarpa Dosha - A Myth or Reality in Astrology?

Tags: vedas, astrology, kundali, horoscopes

What exactly is the Kala Sarpa Dosha or Yoga? Does it actually exist in Vedic astrology?

According to Astrology, what is the mystery behind this?

Comment: There are 12 parts of kundali. Rahu and Ketu always remain opposite to each other(like, when Rahu is in 1st house ketu is in 7th, R in 10- K in 4). So when all the other 7 Grahas come between R and K, then Kaal Sarpa is formed. There are 12 types of Kaal Sarpa. And, I also have a Kaal Sarpa dosh call ShankhaChooda (शंखचूड सर्प) in my Birth Chart.

Comment: It is definitely a dosha. Probably this knowledge of Kalasarpa was carried alone through Oral Tradition, especially from South India, although no classic text mentions this.

Answer (score 2):

Kala Sarpa Yoga is formed when all the planets lie on one side of the nodal axis (Rahu-Ketu axis) in the horoscope.

However, classical Hindu astrological treatise such as Brihat Parasara Hora Shastra, Phaladeepika, Jataka Parijata, Uttara Kalamrita etc., did not mention this yoga (Kala Sarpa Ch. 1. Absence of references in Shastra; p16-21).

Even modern masters like B. V. Raman and K.N. Rao also dismissed its role in natal chart analysis.

The widespread belief in Kala Sarpa Yoga is really unfortunate.

Example of a chart with Kalasarpa Yoga (East Indian chart style):

[image]

Notice that five consecutive houses on one side of the Rahu-Ketu axis are empty.

References:

1. Kaal Sarpa Yoga: Why such fright? by K. N. Rao
2. Three hundred important combinations by B. V. Raman
3. Kala Sarpa by Alan Annand

Comment: Please mention relevant passages from those books or articles or chapter number and page numbers.