# What is "kaal sarpa dosha/yoga"? What are the solutions?

Tags: astrology, yajna, puja, dream, kundali

This is a very famous *dosha/yoga* in certain Kundali-s. There is a [Hindi wikipedia article](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AA_%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%97) about it.

It is said to be formed when all the planets come between Rahu & Ketu during the birth time. People with such *dosha* are supposed to get dreams of snake, water or probably ghosts.

Would like to know in brief from the astrology perspective, whether it is good/bad and how is it resolved?

Comment: [KalaSarpa Dosha - A Myth or Real in Astrology?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23294/5212)

Comment: Rahu and Ketu are the two points where the orbit of sun and orbit of moon (w.r.t. earth) intersect, so R and K are always in opposite position to each other. So, R-K line divides Kundali into two parts. If all 7 Grahas come exactly b/w R-K , then KlSrp Dosh is formed. It is said to be bad, but is not always bad. Not always it shows dreams of Snakes or ghosts. Like Chandaal dosh (Jupiter and R/K together) is said to be bad, but sometimes this leads to spirituality.

Comment: No Dosha can be good or bad without proper studies. Like if Shani is in its neech Rashi(Aires), then Shani gives bad result. But if Mangal is also present with Shani in Aires, then Neech dosh is broken and results in a very good fortune of the person having it. Usually KaalSarp remedies include Vrata of Shiva during Shravan Month, donating Silver Snake et cetera. But an astrologer must be consulted , however a fake astrologer may keep on befooling you for money.