# Is doing shanivaar(Saturday) vrat found in any scripture?

Tags: scripture, hanuman, fasting, shani

If yes, is there any vidhi (procedure) given to observe shanivaar fast?

Is doing shanivaar fast / vrata related to hanumanji?

Comment: Shanivara vrata can be done for Shani Graha too but also for Hanuman. But some people do fasting for Hanuman on tuesdays instead of saturday. The procedure for Shani vrata is mentioned in the hard copy Panjika I have. But it does not mention in which scriptures the procedure is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `Is doing Vrata/Upavāsa on shanivar (Saturday)  found in any scripture?`

**Yes**

In Agni Purāṇa we have a verse, to ameliorate all planetary afflictions.

> अग्नि पुराण [अध्याय १९५](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%AF%E0%A5%AB): वारव्रतानि
>
> मूले शनैश्चरं गृह्य सप्तनक्ती ग्रहार्तिनुत् ॥१९५.००६॥
>
> > 6. **One who resolves to practice eating only seven nights on Saturday in the asterism (Mūla nakṣatra) would destroy all afflictions due to planets.**
>
> Chapter 195: Vows related to the Week-days.
> Translation: From Motilal Banarsidass's [Agni Purāṇa](https://archive.org/details/AgniPuranaUnabridgedEnglishMotilal/page/n530/mode/1up?view=theater)

- For general guidelines on observing Vratas, read [Chapter 175: Vrata-Paribhāṣā](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083404.html)

---

### Remedies for Malefic Śani (Saturn):

- Some homas/yajñas are prescribed in the texts like [Chapter 12: Yajñavalkya Smrti](https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/383/mode/1up?view=theater) to propitiate the nava-grahas, individually and collectively.
- There's even a Śanaiścara-Stotram (शनैश्चरस्तोत्रम्) to ameliorate all malefic effects of grahas, specifically Śani. Here's the [stotra](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/shanaishcharastotram.html). This stotra is found in [Chapter 49 - Śanaiścareśvara](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626837.html) of Section 1 - Prabhāsa-kṣetra-māhātmya from Book 7 - Prabhāsa Khaṇḍa of Skanda Purāṇa .

Infact, god Śiva himself explain the benefits of this stotra as:

> Iśvara (Mahādeva) said -
>
> 59. **If any man gets up early in the morning on a Saturday and recites this Śanaiścara Stotra (Daśarathakṛtam), he will never suffer from affliction caused by any Planet.**

---

Further,

### `Is doing shanivaar vrata related to hanumanji?`

#### No, not as per canonical texts.

Only as per folklore or local (sthala) tales based on oral storytellers (kathāvācaka)  exclusively.

As regards, doing a vrata on Saturday to propitiate god Hanuman to overcome a malefic Śani (Saturn). This is most definitely a recent development from the lanes and likes of '[kala sarpa dosha type astrologers brand](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23294/kalasarpa-dosha-a-myth-or-reality-in-astrology)' i.e. based on popular culture and non-canonical texts, probably over the last century. A phenomenon categorically similar to people performing [Santoṣī Mātā's](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/which-hindu-texts-contains-the-story-of-santoshi-mata-and-about-her-other-legend)  fasts on Friday.

There are folklores and all for relationship between Hanumān and Śani, but nothing canonical exists.

As author Philip Lutgendorf quotes in the book - [Hanuman's Tale](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780195309225.001.0001/acprof-9780195309225)

> The claim that Hanuman’s birth occurred on either a Tuesday or a
> Saturday is often cited as one reason why these are special days for
> his worship. But they are also, according to Indian astrology, the
> most dangerous weekdays, governed by the riskiest planets. Thus
> Mangala or Mars, who presides over Tuesday, is considered a ‘‘sinful
> planet’’ (pāpa graha), and Śani or Saturn is a ‘‘cruel planet’’
> (krūra graha; van der Veer 1988:232). Hanuman’s ability to handle
> dangerous forces (sankaṭ mochan) is being invoked here.....
>
> Page 186

Overall, the author doesn't trace these local stories to any canonical text, but only 'local Upāsanā anthologies' (page 110).

---

### To conclude:

Hanumān's worship on Saturday is not associated with propitiating Śani graha (Saturn), as per any canonical text on Astrology or otherwise.

However, that's not to say, that worshipping Hanumān ji, cannot subvert the malefic planets, yet, I cannot locate any canonical basis for this, to substantiate the claims made.

Comment: is doing shanivaar has to do anything with hanumanji?

Comment: "Is doing shanivaar vrata related to hanumanji? No, not as per canonical texts." how you can be sure that relationship with Shani and hanuman is not present in canonical texts?

Comment: *"how you can be sure that relationship with Shani and hanuman is not present in canonical texts?"* - that's already cited  in the answer @TheDestroyer .  Philip Lutgendorf in his extensively researched book on Hanuman doesn't identify any connection between Hanuman and Shani and Saturday fasting, at least not from any canonical sources,  all these connections, he says are local folklores or *sthala-scriptures.* If you have a source, that refutes my claims, then you are welcome to post an answer and prove my claim wrong.